# I have this error: Ambiguous use of 'locationManager'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location, appdelegate

I'm trying to make a Geofence in Swift 4, but I have a problem, I have an error when calling locationManager, I do not understand why I get this error

this is the error:

> Ambiguous use of locationManager

[image]

I tried to correct it by placing self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation () and other different methods but none worked

Here I declare my variable locationManager:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate{
      locationManager = appDelegate.locationManager
      locationManager.delegate = self
    }
```

This is the code block where I get an error:

```
if let locationManager = self.locationManager{
        let region = self.regionToMonitor()
        if(locationManager.monitoredRegions.count > 0){
            self.geofencesLabel.text = "Geofences OFF"
            locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
            mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)
        }else{
            self.geofencesLabel.text = "Geofences ON"
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
            mapView.add(MKCircle(center: region.center, radius: region.radius))

            nombreU.isHidden = true
            empresaU.isHidden = true
            correoElectronicoU.isHidden = true
            telefonoU.isHidden = true

            //Generamos el registro en la base de datos local en el servidor
            let nombreEvento = self.nombreE
            let nombreOficial = self.nombreO
            let fechaEvento = self.fechaE
            let fechaFormato = self.fechaF
            let lugarEvento = self.lugarE
            let descripcionEvento = self.descripcionE
            let imagenEvento = self.imagenE
            let latitudEvento = self.latitudE
            let longitudEvento = self.longitudE
            let empresaEvento = self.empresaE
            let rolEvento = self.rolE

            //Recuperamos el contenido de las cajas de texto para validarlo
            let nombreC = self.nombreU.text!
            let empresaC = self.empresaU.text!
            let correoC = self.correoElectronicoU.text!
            let telefonoC = self.telefonoU.text!

            //Validamos que no este vacio ninguna de los datos recibidos del servidor y ninguna de las cajas de texto

            if(nombreC.isEmpty || empresaC.isEmpty || correoC.isEmpty || telefonoC.isEmpty){
                displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Todos los campos deben ser llenados")
                return
            }

            if(nombreEvento.isEmpty || nombreOficial.isEmpty || fechaEvento.isEmpty || fechaFormato.isEmpty || lugarEvento.isEmpty || descripcionEvento.isEmpty){
                displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Ocurrio un error al cargar los eventos")
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }

            //Ingresamos los valores a la base de datos local
            let newEvento = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Eventos", into: context)
            newEvento.setValue(nombreEvento, forKey: "nombreE")
            newEvento.setValue(nombreOficial, forKey: "nombreO")
            newEvento.setValue(fechaEvento, forKey: "fechaE")
            newEvento.setValue(fechaFormato, forKey: "fechaF")
            newEvento.setValue(lugarEvento, forKey: "lugarE")
            newEvento.setValue(descripcionEvento, forKey: "descripcionE")
            newEvento.setValue(imagenEvento, forKey: "imagenE")
            newEvento.setValue(latitudEvento, forKey: "latitudE")
            newEvento.setValue(longitudEvento, forKey: "longitudE")
            newEvento.setValue(empresaEvento, forKey: "empresaE")
            newEvento.setValue(rolEvento, forKey: "rolE")

            nombreU.isHidden = true
            empresaU.isHidden = true
            correoElectronicoU.isHidden = true
            telefonoU.isHidden = true

            //Mostramos mensaje de que ya estas registrado
            mensajeRegistro.text = "Gracias por registrarte a nuestro evento"
            mensajeRegistro.isHidden = false


            do{
                try context.save()
                print("El registro al evento se realizo de forma correcta")
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }

            //Ejecutamos el codigo del WebService
            guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.sitioweb.mx/webservice/registro.php?nombre=\(nom)&empresa=\(empresaC)&correo=\(corC)&telefono=\(telC)") else { return }

            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if let response = response {
                    print(response)
                }else{
                    print(error!)
                }
            }
        }

    }else{
        notify(msg: "El geofence no esta disponible")
    }
```

My class has this extension:

```
// MARK: - Location Manager Delegate
extension RegistroViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = status == .authorizedAlways
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
        print("Monitoring failed for region with identifier: \(region!.identifier)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Location Manager failed with the following error: \(error)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Location update")
    }

}
```

I do not understand what is wrong or what method I should refer to when calling self.locationManager

This is my Appdelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import CoreLocation
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    static var menu_bool = true
    static var menu_boolS = true

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        locationManager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.badge, .sound, .alert]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options){ success, error in
            if let error = error{
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Is the device's location something that multiple view controllers will need or just this one?

Comment: Just only in this

Comment: And is this view controller instantiated at app launch?

Comment: Do you mean if you are in the Appdelegate?

Comment: Setting up the location manager should be one of the very first things the application does because getting an accurate location is an asynchronous event (and it can take some time). So if this view controller fires up as the app launches and only this view controller needs device location, then I think it's fine to handle location in this view controller. However, if both of those are not true, then I'd configure location in the app delegate.

Comment: `locationManager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate` is incorrect. The app delegate needs to conform to that protocol; you must not be casting the delegate `as? CLLocationManagerDelegate`. Remove the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate extension in `RegistroViewController` and handle all of the location delegation in the app delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `locationManager` is an instance property use it directly

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

---

```
    let region = self.regionToMonitor()
    if(locationManager.monitoredRegions.count > 0){
        self.geofencesLabel.text = "Geofences OFF"
        locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
        mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)
    }else{
        self.geofencesLabel.text = "Geofences ON"
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        mapView.add(MKCircle(center: region.center, radius: region.radius))
```

Without

```
if let locationManager = self.locationManager{
```

Comment: If I remove the if now the error is given to me in the following line:

locationManager.monitoredRegions.count, now the error is "Ambiguous reference to member 'locationManager (_: didenterRegion :)'"

Comment: Do you add a closing `}` to `if let locationManager = self.locationManager{`

Comment: Yes, if it is locationManager = self.locationManager {, it had a closing but also remove it, I do not have errors in the open or close keys

Comment: can you share that relevant part of the vc where you declare the manger and set the above block

Comment: why you still have `if let locationManager = self.locationManager{` is `self.locationManager{` optional remove it with it's else , compile and run

Comment: where you do `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()`  ??

Comment: That's in my viewDidLoad (), add it to the beginning of the question

Comment: take it out of the function it should be an instace variable

Comment: Also why you add the instance inside the appdelegate ? do you need it else where or inside this vc only if latter declare it directly inside that vc

Comment: you can say  `self ` here `self.locationManager` only if it's an instance variable not local

Comment: I have in the AppDelegate is to choose the location permissions and also be able to send notifications, I add the code block that I use in the AppDelegate, this is the only VC that uses the location

Comment: tried to set `var locationManager = CLLocationManager()` out of the function ?

Comment: I already worked, just declare let locationManager = CLLocationManager () and removed the if you mentioned

Comment: Thank you very much for the help